# Como fazer Vetor/Array de inteiros indexado por strings?

Tags: c++

Como faço um vetor/array de números inteiros com strings como índice?

Algo que em Lua seria:

```
vetor = {
    ["eu"] = 10,
    ["voce"] = 11,
}
```

ps: Será dinamico, logo não terá um tamanho fixo.
ps²: **Struct** ou **enum** não servem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possivelmente vício do PHP né, já passei por isso, acho que a solução mais próxima a isso é o std:map

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map <std::string, int> data{
     { "Maria", 10 },
     { "Joao", 15 },
     { "Anabelo", 34 },
     { "Fulaninho", 22 },
    };

    for (const auto& element : data)
    {
        std::cout << "Chave(key = first): " << element.first;
        std::cout << "Valor(value = second): " << element.second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: Serviu perfeitamente.

Answer (score 2):

Em C não é possível (não sei C++).

Em C os indices de arrays são obrigatoriamente números inteiros.

O que podes fazer é converter a string num número (único) e usar esse número como indíce para o array (operação normalmente conhecida como *hashing*)

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* esta função de hash() e muito basica. NAO USAR! */
int hash(const char *index) {
    return *index == 'e';
}

int main(void) {
    int vetor[2] = {11, 10};

    printf("eu ==> %d\n", vetor[hash("eu")]);
    printf("voce ==> %d\n", vetor[hash("voce")]);
    return 0;
}
```

O *truque* está na escolha da função `hash()`.

Há bibliotecas já feitas que facilitam este processo.

Comment: Sabe se o BOOST tem alguma(biblioteca)?

Comment: ver exemplo no ideone: http://ideone.com/9nyS18

Comment: Gabriel, não conheço BOOST.

Comment: @pmg como você mesmo mostrou é possível sim. Não terá facilidade sintática. Dá para fazer de outras formas diferentes da sua também. Todas ficarão meio feias mas é possível. Boost é biblioteca C++. Grande parte do que existe em Boost tem uma forma parecida na biblioteca padrão do C++ nas versões mais recentes.